# SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql

I have a table in sql in which I inserted my another table names.There are Table names column.So is it possible (programmatically inside SQL)  getting the table names from this column and use them in Stored procedure as table name.How?inside SQL.
thanks

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Short answer is YES. You can use dynamic queries.

Comment: Most dbs have system tables that make your own table unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like something you will need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) to do.  Before you rush off to do this, I would recommend reading this article:

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html